# \Magento\Framework\Registry deprecated in magento 2.3, How to create instance with Registry?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, registry

```
/**
 * Registry model. Used to manage values in registry
 *
 * Registry usage as a shared service introduces temporal, hard to detect coupling into system.
 * It's usage should be avoid. Use service classes or data providers instead.
 *
 * @api
 * @deprecated
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
```

> https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-registry-register.html

[image]

Who can show me a demo that use service classes or data providers instead.

thx.

Answer (score 10):

Here you can find the way how to avoid usage of `Registry` - https://www.atwix.com/development/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/

Comment: By the above link it's possible only to get the data and not to set the data.
Is there's a way to set data without registry?

Comment: @Haerriz you might be interested in Vinai's solution https://github.com/Vinai/module-current-product-example

Answer (score 5):

The correct way of getting the current product on PDP page without using registry class is to use Catalog Helper class.

```
public function __construct(    
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogHelper
) {
    $this->catalogHelper = $catalogHelper;
}

public function run() {
    $this->catalogHelper->getProduct();
}
```

By looking at the implementation you will see that it is still using registry class under the hood, but that is okay because when core class will be refactored to not use registry class, your code will not break and you should still get your product. This is the whole purpose of the helper class, essentially you are shifting responsibility to the framework from your own implementation, which is the best you can do in this scenario.

[image]

Comment: It is not ok because this helper is not marked with `@api` tag. The `@api` tag guarantees that public interface (methods) won't be changed in the future non-major updates.

Comment: @MTP you may be right but there is no alternative to that at the moment, this is still better than using method that has been marked deprecated.