# Magento 2.4.4: Register is deprecated

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento2.4, backend, register

I recently noticed the line `$this->registry->register` with register striked through. Mouseover displayed a message saying Register is deprecated. Could you please direct me to what is the alternative to this now? Thank you all. I am using the code below in the custom module.

```
    case "stripe_payments":
        // We need to set the current_order in registry, as StripeIntegration script info.php uses this registry.
        // Instantiate the StripeIntegration Info class after setting the registry.
        $this->registry->**register**('current_order', $order);
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $stripePayment = $objectManager->get('StripeIntegration\Payments\Block\Adminhtml\Payment\Info');

        // Now, we can make the calls to retrieve the Stripe details for the Credit card.
        $this->get_credit_card_payment_info($order_info, $stripePayment->getCard());
        $order_info["cc_name"] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        $order_info["cc_veri"] = $order->getPayment()->getTransactionId();
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a comment in \Magento\Framework\Registry that states:

> Registry usage as a shared service introduces temporal, hard to detect
> coupling into system. Its usage should be avoided. Use service classes
> or data providers instead.

Note that these deprecations warnings were added Mar 24, 2018. There are still thousands of uses in Magento's core modules.

I can't find any "officially" recommended alternatives.

Searching the web I found:

1. https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/#alternatives
2. A similar question to yours, but from 2019 (which references 1): [\Magento\Framework\Registry deprecated in magento 2.3, How to create instance with Registry?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257194/magento-framework-registry-deprecated-in-magento-2-3-how-to-create-instance-wi)

Between the ongoing, widespread use of registry in the core and the lack of recommended alternatives, I'm not personally concerned about using it for now. By the time it is actually removed, I expect there to be thousands of alternative implementations to review.

If that isn't acceptable, I think the key section from that first link is:

> **Where to get data from, if not Registry?**
>
> The short answer is “from the session”.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Could you please help me with an example of service class or data provider to replace the existing code around registry in my code above?

Comment: Personally, I haven't created or even seen an example of using service classes/data providers to replace the registry. I updated my answer with some possible resources.

Comment: It is also worth noting that there are ~100 uses of the registry and "current_order" alone. Any change to the custom module would have to account for this.