# Registry & Services

Tags: magento2, session, registry, deprecated

Can Any body explain me Why Magneto used registry and now why we use Services for what purposes instead of Registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a lot of useful information you can find in following question [\Magento\Framework\Registry deprecated in magento 2.3, How to create instance with Registry?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257194/magento-framework-registry-deprecated-in-magento-2-3-how-to-create-instance-wi)

I want to talk and show another one example in core and in my opinion this is controversial decision and implementation. In the end we continue to use `\Magento\Framework\Registry` anyway.

Lets see into `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface` (removed comments for simplify)

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface;

/**
 * Interface LocatorInterface
 *
 */
interface LocatorInterface
{
    public function getProduct();
    public function getStore();
    public function getWebsiteIds();
    public function getBaseCurrencyCode();
}
```

This interface uses in a lot of places like `$this->locator->getProduct()`

In implementation \Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\RegistryLocator which is default one you can see:

```php
<?php

namespace Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface;

/**
 * Class RegistryLocator
 */
class RegistryLocator implements LocatorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @var ProductInterface
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var StoreInterface
     */
    private $store;

    /**
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(Registry $registry)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @throws NotFoundException
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (null !== $this->product) {
            return $this->product;
        }

        if ($product = $this->registry->registry('current_product')) {
            return $this->product = $product;
        }

        throw new NotFoundException(__("The product wasn't registered."));
    }

    // ...
}
```

As you can see the locator (service) continue to use `\Magento\Framework\Registry`.

I cannot find any best practices or recommendation from Magento team or any examples in documentation.

I guess the comment about deprecate in `Registry` more made for force developers to create some additional layer for get some registry values and you should not to use registry directly. I repeat, in my opinion this is very strange and controversial decision for use registry pattern.

Comment: But you can also use data persistor instead of registry also.

Comment: Registry and Data Persistor have different logic. Data Persistor sets data into session and needs to pass data between requests, Registry works only in single request scope and needs to pass data between classes.

Comment: okay got it. Thank you.

Comment: Can we use service classes instead of registry in the magento 2